# Solution to the ratio of Jacobi theta functions

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions

How can I find the solution (when exists) for

$\dfrac{\vartheta(z;\tau)}{\vartheta(z+\frac{1}{2};\tau)}=a$

where $\vartheta(z;\tau)$ is the Jacobi theta function $\theta_3(z;q)$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$.

I landed at these functions from wrapped normal distribution functions and I don't have much analysis background. I borrowed the notation from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapped_normal_distribution) and hope it is correct and clear.

Comment: When $z\in \Bbb{Q}$ there is a way, finding the $\Bbb{C}(j(\tau))$ minimal polynomial of $\dfrac{\vartheta(z;\tau)^4}{\vartheta(z+\frac{1}{2};\tau)^4}$ and solving the obtained polynomial equation in $j(\tau)$.

Comment: what's a minimal polynomial? is there a systematic way to find it?

Comment: The $\Bbb{R}$-minimal polynomial of $i$ is $x^2+1$. Yes but it is complicated.

Comment: Then this probably doesn't have much to do with the $\theta_3$ function. Did I get that right? Is there a closed-form minimal polynomial for that ratio of $\theta$ functions?